# Can someone please help me to prove that the Cholesky factorization of Matrix $A$ in complex space $m\times m?$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have proof when $A$ is real. That is by assuming $A$ has $2$ different Cholesky factorizations and then showing that the upper triangular is equal to lower triangular and by using diagonal matrix.
But I am not sure if its valid to complex.

Comment: What exactly is in question? The Cholesky decomposion, as well as the LDLT decomposition, has a simple straightforward algorithm that leaves no room for ambiguity. The uniqueness of the result should be no more in doubt than that of $2+2$. Are you exploring the solution space of the equation $CC^T=A$ and all the special forms that $C$ can take?

Comment: Yes, I'm exploring the solution space in complex. One particular Algorithms gives unique factorization but that doesn't prove that the factorization is unique right?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid question to ask how many structural demands one can make until the result is unique. But what is the point of departure, and what is your definition of "Cholesky"?